# To find a point in the intersection of convex sets why do we use this as a possible subgradient?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, projection, subgradient

[Screenshot of the notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f18Hh.png)

I am going through the notes of Stephen Boyd and I come across this. I cannot understand why is this a subgradient of the said function? Please check the image attached herewith.

$ g = \frac{x - \Pi_{C_{j}}}{\|x - \Pi_{C_{j}}\|_2}$

$\Pi_{C_{j}}$ is the Euclidean projection onto the convex set $C_{j}$  meaning this point ($\Pi_{C_{j}}$) on $C_{j}$ is closest to the point $x$ outside the convex set.

The denominator, $ \|x - \Pi_{C_{j}}\|_2$, is a Euclidean distance. The numerator, $x - \Pi_{C_{j}}$ is a vector. I cannot seem to wrap my head around this subgradient.

Comment: The algorithm described in these notes is the method of alternating projections.  By moving in the direction from $x$ to $\Pi_{C_{j}}$ you get closer to the set $C_{j}$.

Comment: Ahh, so the given subgradient is a unit vector and by scaling it by the step size alpha we go in the negative direction of the subgradient, that is towards the set Cj. Thank you, Brian Borchers.

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear what your question is asking.

We have $f(x) = \max_k d_{C_k}(x)$, where $d_{C_k} (x) = \min_{c \in C_k} \|x-c\|$. Each of the functions $d_{C_k}$ is regular hence 
$\partial f(x) = \operatorname{co} \{ \partial d_{C_k}(x)\}_{k \in I(x)}$, where
$I(x) = \{ k | f(x) = d_{C_k}(x) \}$ (see Clarke, "Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis", Proposition 2.3.12, for example).

Hence to find a sugbradient $g$ of $f$ it suffices to find a
subgradient of any of the 'active' distances.

The notation in the linked picture incorrectly suggests that the distance function has a gradient. This is true ae. by the Rademacher theorem but not necessarily true everywhere. However, the given vector **is** a sugradient.

As an aside, to illustrate the previous point, let $C=\operatorname{epi} g \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ where $g(x) = 1+|x|$. Then we can compute $d_C((t,0)) = \max(0,|t|-1)$,
which is not differentiable at $|t|=1$.

To see that the given vector is a subgradient, note that we can compute **a** subgradient of $d_C$ at $x_0$ in the following manner, noting that $C$ is contained in a
suitable supporting hyperplane $H$:

Suppose $d_C(x_0)=\|x_0-c_0\| >0$, where $c_0 \in C$ (that is, $c_0 = \Pi_C(x)$ using the notation in the attached picture). Note that
$C \subset H = \{ x | \langle x-c_0, c_0-x_0 \rangle \ge 0 \}$, 
$d_C(x) \ge d_H(x)$ for all $x$ and $d_H(x_0) = d_C(x_0)$.

A quick computation shows that $d_H(x) = | \langle {x_0-c_0 \over \|x_0-c_0|} , x-c_0 \rangle |$, and since $d_C \ge 0$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
d_C(x) &\ge& \langle {x_0-c_0 \over \|x_0-c_0 \|} , x-c_0 \rangle \\
&=& \langle {x_0-c_0 \over \|x_0-c_0 \|} , x-x_0 \rangle + \langle {x_0-c_0 \over \|x_0-c_0 \|} , x_0-c_0 \rangle \\
&=& d_C(x_0) + \langle {x_0-c_0 \over \|x_0-c_0 \|} , x-x_0 \rangle
\end{eqnarray}
 for
all $x$. Hence ${x_0-c_0 \over \|x_0-c_0 \|} \in \partial d_C(x_0)$.